# How can I update a subdocument in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, put, subdocument

Code created in Mongoose to update a subdocument was not working.  So I tried to update the subdocument within the Mongo Shell.
This is the document (location) and subdocument (review):

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("56d8c73314fbc7e702cfb8c4"),
"name" : "Costly",
"address" : "150, Super Street",
"coords" : [
    -0.9630884,
    51.451041
],
"reviews" : [
    {
        "author" : "kyle riggen1",
        "_id" : ObjectId("56d8de74cc7f953efd8455d9"),
        "rating" : 4,
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2015-06-01T06:00:00Z"),
        "reviewText" : "will the ID work?"
    }
],
"rating" : 0,
"__v" : 2
```

}

Here are some of my attempts at updating the subdocument:
[This question gave this format:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646798/mongodb-updating-subdocument)

```
update({ 
       _id: "56d8c73314fbc7e702cfb8c4", 
       "reviews._id": ObjectId("56d8de74cc7f953efd8455d9")
   },{
       $set: {"reviews.$.rating": 1}
   }, false, true
);
```

This returned an error of "update is not defined" as shown:

```
2016-03-03T22:52:44.445-0700 E QUERY    [thread1] ReferenceError: update is not defined :
@(shell):1:1
```

Which I think is because the command did not start with db.locations.update()

[MongoDB documentation used this format:](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

```
db.locations.update(
   {
     _id: "56d8c73314fbc7e702cfb8c4",
     review: { $elemMatch: { author: "kyle riggen1" } }
   },
   { $set: { "location.$.rating" : 1 } }
)
```

This returns a valid update but the update didn't actually happen as shown:

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

[This question used this format:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173482/mongodb-update-deeply-nested-subdocument)

```
db.locations.update({
    _id: "56d8c73314fbc7e702cfb8c4",
    'review.author': 'kyle riggen1'
  },
  { $set: { 'review.$.rating': 1 }}
)
```

This returns the same as the MongoDB documentation as shown here:

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

So these queries I guess are working but my data is not getting updated.  Would my data be indexed wrong perhaps?  The actual location is able to be updated even through a Mongoose API.

Comment: Woul'd you like to take another crack at choosing a title that isn't going to offend anyone or otherwise embarass you when people give the simple explanation? And of course that explaination is `ObjectId("56d8c73314fbc7e702cfb8c4")`. Oops, you forgot to cast your string.

Comment: @BlakesSeven fixed title to a more appropriate question.  The ObjectId() only appears in my mongo shell.  The API produces an ID without it.  I have edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: What API? All of your examples ( and every error and response ) are being issed from the MongoDB shell. The values you are passing to `_id` in the query need to be an `ObjectId`, otherwise they will not match. That's exactly what is happening here. Only something like `mongoose` will autocast a string as it's schema type for you, but you are not executing any of your samples in mongoose.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I see ok giving that a try

Comment: @BlakesSeven And that worked!  Would you mind submitting an answer so I can give you credit to my silly question?

Comment: I actually marked it for a close already, since a fairly clear omission of casting to an `ObjectId` is a pretty basic mistake, and already credited to answers and questions submitted many years before. Next time, pay attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it By $push Or $addToSet.

```
db.col.update(
        { name: 'reviews', 'list.id': 2 }, 
        {$push: {'list.$.items': {id: 5, name: 'item5'}}}
    )
```

See the reference from mongodb Manual

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/

Answer (score -1):

Please know `db.collection.update( criteria, objNew, upsert, multi )`

1. `criteria`: match condition
2. `objNew`: update content
3. `upsert`: true or false

   - true : if not existed, insert it
   - false : if not existed, don't insert
4. `multi`: true or false

   - true : update all matched documents
   - false : only update the first matched document

Comment: I'm sorry ,this is my first answer.  I am not familiar with this forum。 I can familiar with this as soons as possible