# how to search for specific object inside an object in mongo to perform an update

Tags: json, mongodb

I have JSON of persons, each person has a list of kids:

```
{
  "name": ":John",
  "age": 35,
  "kids": [
    {
      "name": "tom",
      "age": 5
    },
    {
      "name": "tina",
      "age": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to perform `findAndModify` where the person name is "John" and the kid name is "tina" and update her age to 7.

This is my query so far:

```
db.people.findAndModify({
    query: { "name" : "John" {--HERE--}},
    update: { $set: { "age" : 7 } }
})
```

What do I need to replace `--HERE--` with to find the kid named "tina"?

Comment: I think you should be more concerned about why your daughter is ageing so much quicker than anyone else!

Comment: @musefan haha, good one :)

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: Updating subdocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646798/mongodb-updating-subdocument)

Comment: So according o the dupe mentioned by Alex, does this work: `{ "name" : "John", "kids.name" : "tina" }` with set as `$set: {"kids.$.age": 7}`

Comment: @musefan it works to help find the document yes, but when i do ```update: { $set: { "age" : 7 } }``` its updating the name of the person, its not updating the child document...

Comment: @JohnBigs: I updated my comment... though I am just basing my answer from the dupe. I have never used mongodb before :/

Comment: @musefan yes what you wrote in the comment works...:) thanks buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than having half an answer in the comments, here is the full example which should do what you need:

```
db.people.findAndModify({
    query: { "name" : "John", "kids.name" : "tina"},
    update: { $set: { "kids.$.age" : 7} }
})
```